# Changing the format of pairs of years in a vector in R

Tags: r, string, substring, stringr

I was wondering if it might be possible to change the format of my `Input` to my `Desired_output`?

```
Input= c("20192020","20202021","20212022")

Desired_output= c("2019-20","2020-21","2021-22")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `sub()` here:

```r
Input <- c("20192020", "20202021", "20212022")
out <- sub("\\d{2}(\\d{2})$", "-\\1", Input)
out

[1] "2019-20" "2020-21" "2021-22"
```